# What's the purpose of specifying IndexDirection for indexes in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, annotations, indexing, morphia

I am using Morphia to communicate with MongoDb. When annotating fields with @Indexed, it's allowed to specify the IndexDirection of DESC, ASC, BOTH, GEO2D, what's the purpose of those separately?

If I specify BOTH, does it mean that there would have two indexes created?

And also, if I want the filtered entities to be order in descending order, does it mean that I'd better to have the index to have IndexDirection of DESC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC = Descending, ASC = Ascending, and GEO2D = 2D/Geography

BOTH is not a valid option unfortunately. That was a mistake of the enum definition and no longer exists.

They indicate how the values are stored in the index. For a single index the direction is not important.

For compound indexes you can specify the orders for each field and it will make a difference. See the docs on the mongodb site for [specifics](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes).